# how to setup MPEG-DASH in mac?

Tags: mpeg-dash, ttml

I wants to do a MPEG-DASH setup with ttml(Any Audio and Video is fine).

But wants to put my own TTML content.

Is it available in any link ?
I am having mac & ubunthu

Comment: hello @senthil, Welcome to SO. You should always add some more description to your asked question. Some description that shows a reflection of the fact that how you tried to solve the problem first and what made you fail. This way you will get more help rather just asking for a direct solution or link. Hope that help for a better journey at SO. Best of luck

Comment: As @TasnimFabiha das indicated you should provide some more specifics. I can guess that you are perhaps looking at a way to create DASH files and publish those videos in a standard player like Shaka or Dash.js with a sidecar TTML file that you have created. I would look at this article to start https://rybakov.com/blog/mpeg-dash/